# JFrame using way too much memory

Tags: java, swing, memory, jframe, memory-leaks

I'm currently working on a 2D game. I have a JFrame that adds a JPanel.  For some reason, the program is using more and more memory every second. It starts out at about 50,000K and goes higher and higher until my computer can't handle it. I thought it was the `paint()` method being called in my JPanel, but when I don't add my JPanel, it's still going up. Here is the code for my JFrame:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import level.Level;

public class LostCloud {

public static int width = 300;
public static int height = 300;
public static int scale = 2;
public static String name = "Lost Cloud: Adventure 2D";
public static JFrame frame;
public static JFrame levelFrame;
public static Component center = null;
public static Menu menu = new Menu();
public static Level level = new Level();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    frame = new JFrame(name);
    levelFrame = new JFrame(name);

    // Set size and settings
    frame.setSize(width * 2, height * 2);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(center);
    // Set visible
    frame.setVisible(true);
    // Draw main menu panel

    frame.add(menu);
    menu.requestFocusInWindow();
    frame.validate();
}

public void play() {

    //Close main menu frame
    frame.dispose();

    // Set size and settings
            levelFrame.setSize(width * 3, height * 3);
            levelFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            levelFrame.setResizable(false);
            levelFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(center);
            // Set visible
            levelFrame.setVisible(true);
            // Draw level panel

            levelFrame.add(level);
            level.requestFocusInWindow();
            levelFrame.validate();
        }
}
```

Menu:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import entity.PlayerEntity;

public class Menu extends JPanel {

// Animations

public int animating = 0;
public int animatingType = 0;

// Selected

public int selectedOption = 0;

//Images

public BufferedImage background;
public String backgroundLocation;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private PlayerEntity player;
public LostCloud main = new LostCloud();

public Menu() {
    player = new PlayerEntity(400, 200);
    addKeyListener(new MenuKeyListener());


    // Data file, stores name in it

    File file = new File("data.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("Cloud");
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void updatePaint() {
    this.repaint();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    updatePaint();
    final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    backgroundLocation = "res/background/main/main_background.png";
    try {
        background = ImageIO.read(new File(backgroundLocation));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to find file " + backgroundLocation + ",      printing stack trace!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    g2.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

    Font font = null;

    try {
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(
                "res/font/BitTrip7(sRB).TTF"));
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    font = font.deriveFont(40F);
    g.setFont(font);



    if (selectedOption == 0) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("Play", LostCloud.width / 2, 350);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Quit", LostCloud.width / 2, 400);
    } else if (selectedOption == 1) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Play", LostCloud.width / 2, 350);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("Quit", LostCloud.width / 2, 400);
    }


    if (animatingType == 0) {
        g2.drawImage(player.sprite[0].getScaledInstance(128, 128,
                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), player.x, player.y, null);
    } else if (animatingType == 1) {
        g2.drawImage(player.sprite[1].getScaledInstance(128, 128,
                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), player.x, player.y, null);
    }
    if (animating == 0) {
        g2.drawImage(player.sprite[1], 10, 10, null);
        animating = 1;

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if (animatingType == 0) {
                    animatingType = 1;
                } else if (animatingType == 1) {
                    animatingType = 0;
                }
            }
        }, 0, 2 * 1000);
    }
}

private class MenuKeyListener implements KeyListener {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            if (selectedOption == 1) {
                selectedOption = 0;
            }
        }

        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            if (selectedOption == 0) {
                selectedOption = 1;
            }
        }

        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            if (selectedOption == 0) {
                main.play();
            }
        }


    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

}
}
```

Level:

```
package level;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import entity.PlayerEntity;

public class Level extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Timer time;

// Player

public PlayerEntity player;

// Collisions

public static Rectangle bottom = new Rectangle(0, 500, 1000, 200);

public Level() {
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    player = new PlayerEntity(200, 200);
    addKeyListener(new LevelKeyListener());

    time = new Timer(5, this);
    time.start();
}

public void updatePaint() {
    this.repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    updatePaint();

    final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.fill(bottom);
    if (player.attacking == 0) {
        g2.drawImage(player.sprite[1].getScaledInstance(64, 64,
                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), player.x, player.y, null);
    } else if (player.attacking == 1) {
        g2.drawImage(player.sprite[2].getScaledInstance(64, 64,
                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), player.x, player.y, null);
    }



    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Font font = null;

    try {
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(
                "res/font/BitTrip7(sRB).TTF"));
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    font = font.deriveFont(30F);
    g2.setFont(font);
    g2.drawString(String.valueOf(player.getCharge()) + "%", 250, 100);
    g2.drawString(String.valueOf(player.getHealth()) + "%", 250, 50);

    g2.drawImage(player.getStatImage().getScaledInstance(256, 128, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0, 0, null);

    Rectangle chargeRect = new Rectangle(28, 74, player.getCharge() * 2 - 1, 24);
    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g2.fill(chargeRect);

    Rectangle healthRect = new Rectangle(28, 26, player.getHealth() * 2 - 1,      24);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(healthRect);
}

private class LevelKeyListener implements KeyListener {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        player.keyPressed(event);

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
        player.keyReleased(key);

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

    }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    player.move();
    updatePaint();
    revalidate();
}
}
```

Comment: Add a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Have you tried a profiler like [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/)?

Comment: @karlphillip that's all my code O_o, you don't need the JPanel class because it's not being called.  Help plz, I can't continue my game without this fixed..

Comment: What is `Level`? Some sort of custom component? I guess the problem lies there... Replacing `Level` with an orginary `JPanel` there is no problem. Also, what's `Menu`?

Comment: @tobias_k no, I don't think so.  Level is another JPanel that i call from my Menu class. Neither of those are being called.

Comment: Why dont you just use VisualVM? Profile the thing, find out what object types are filling up RAM, and go to the places in code where they are being created. or if you're using netbeans or some other IDE with a built in profiler, do it that way.

Comment: And the above code is still giving you those memory problems? `Menu` and `Level` may not be used, but you create instances of them. Maybe that's enough to clog up your memory.

Comment: This is NOT all your code.  You are instantiating things we cannot see.  Boil your problem down to the smallest compilable, runnable example you can and then give us ALL of it.  If you don't understand what's wrong, then you cannot possibly judge what code is relevant.

Comment: @tobias_k i removed all of my instances, and the memory isn't going up anymore, but i still need the instances, i'll guess ill find a different way to do this.

Comment: I agree with rcook.  Cut it down to the smallest compilable runnable example that still replicates the problem.  If you're using an IDE like Netbeans, you can also place breakpoints in your code and use them to narrow down where the problem lies.  Good luck!

Comment: @user3234092 But now at least you have it narrowed down. Try to remove just Level or just Menu, and see which one caused the problem, and then post that code, too, particularly the constructor, since that's what seems to cause the problem. Either that, or their paint methods.

Comment: @tobias_k I've narrowed it down, and it seems to be doing it when I make an instance of Menu OR Level.  I'll post the code in the thread.

Comment: Now my guess would be that the problem is in the constructor of `PlayerEntity`, since that's created in both classes. Also, do you really want to have two of those? Also, calling `repaint` inside of `paint` is a really bad idea, but that should rather cause super-high CPU load, not high memory consumption.

Comment: @tobias_k what would be a better way to constantly update my paint() method then...

Comment: Not sure either (newer made a game with swing), but maybe that Timer would be a good (at least better) place. Also, you should rather implement `paintComponent` than paint, and load and cache those images before painting instead of in each call to paint.

Comment: Move the calls to `ImageIO.read()` and `Font.createFont()` out of `paint()`. I believe either or both will cache what they read (but am not sure, so am not making this an answer).

Comment: @kdgregory THANK YOU!  It's not longer using a ton of memory :D

Comment: Tip: If you want to program a 2D-Game and it shall be a bit more complicated (like a RPG-Tile-based game), better stick to Slick 2D for Java. You will love it and it makes work easier, compared to Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Check with adding `ActionListeners`. If you add action listeners with `new` due to some event or based on time(as it sounds from it increasing without you doing anything) then you could be allocating memory for the listener each time. This creates a memory leak which can lead to the gradual increase in memory requirements until failure. Try to add the action listeners to an instance variable so that they only have to be instantiated once. I don't see all your code so I am just saying this from experience on a project and running into similar problems.